# MultiLabelBinarizer error (characters instead of entries)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, nlp, multilabel-classification

**this is my dataframe column**

```
y = df['tags']
y
```

**Output**

```
0       Brand Design,Website Development,WordPress Des...
1       Motion Graphics,Video Editing,Graphic Design,L...
2       Business Proposal Writing,Content Writing,Copy...
3       Content Writing,Article Writing,Social Media M...
4                  PHP,React native,Laravel Framework,C#]
                              ...                        
2995    Ad Design,Adobe Illustrator,Adobe Photoshop,Co...
2996    Administrative Support,Accounting Executive In...
2997    Administrative Support,Business Analytics,Comp...
2998    .NET Development,AngularJS,ASP.NET MVC,Automat...
2999        3D Animation,2D Design,3D Design,3D Modeling]
Name: tags, Length: 3000, dtype: object
```

**Initialize**

```
multilabel = MultiLabelBinarizer()    
y = multilabel.fit_transform(df['tags'])
y
```

**Output**

```
array([[1, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 0, ..., 0, 1, 0],
       ...,
       [1, 0, 0, ..., 0, 1, 0],
       [1, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0]])
```

**By calling**

```
multilabel.classes_
```

**Output - It is showing the characters present instead I want all the entries present in the 'tags' column**

```
array([' ', '!', '#', '&', "'", '(', ')', '+', ',', '-', '.', '/', '0',
       '1', '2', '3', '5', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I',
       'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V',
       'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z', '\\', ']', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g',
       'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't',
       'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z'], dtype=object)
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the [Documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.MultiLabelBinarizer.html), your problem is described there:

> A common mistake is to pass in a list, which leads to the following
> issue: ...

If you want to use `MultiLabelBinarizer()` you have to pass not list of sentences but list of list of words like this:

```
multilabel = MultiLabelBinarizer()    
y = multilabel.fit_transform([[word] for text in df['tag'] for word in text.split()])
```

And I also would suggest you to use `CountVectorizer` when it comes to encoding sentences:

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
multilabel = CountVectorizer()    
y = multilabel.fit_transform(df['tag'])
```